# DNA sequence counting

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a sequence of DNA separated by some white space. I need to remove the white spaces and return the count of the sequence without the white space characters. Any help on how to do that? I am using a terminal with bash.

For example, the sequence looks like this:

```
GTCGATTGCAAGGATCCGCATGGGATAAAGGAATCGCAGTTCGAACAGGCAATGCCGCAG
CTATGATAGGACATCTCTTGGAGACACCTATTAATGTTTCAGAAACGGATACCTTGGTTG
TCCAGTACGAAATTAAGTTGGACAATTCTTTGACGTGCGGC
CTATATTAAAATTGTGGGTACATCACTCTCTTACCTGAGAATTCCAACAGAGCAGGACGC
TAACCCAGTGTCTATACCAGTCTGTGGCTTTGAAAGATTAGACACATTTCTGGATGAATT
TTCAAATTCTAAATTGATCGTTCAGTCTACACTAAGACATTCGTACGTTAGTCTTGAGAA
```

I want to remove the white space and have an exact count of how many bases are there. Alternatively, we could count how many As, or Cs, or Gs or Ts are present and add them without counting white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` `sort` `uniq`:

```
$ grep -oP '\w' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Or

```
$ grep -o '[A-Z]' file | sort | uniq -c
```

Or for only `G`:

```
$ grep -o 'G' file | uniq -c
```

or

```
$ grep -o 'G' file | wc -l
```

### Output

```
101 A
 68 C
 74 G
 98 T
```

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks a lot. it worked. I appreciate your help. If I wanted to count how many "G" I had in the sequence, will  this work?:     $ grep -oP 'G' file | sort | uniq -c

Comment: `grep -o 'G' file | uniq -c`

Comment: Hello Gilles, isn't it over powered to used `--perl-regexp` option ? As it in this example you only need to count `A`, `C`, `G`, `T`, `[ACGT]` would work and only need basic regular expressions

Comment: Added solution without PCRE

Answer (score 2):

Using a Perl one liner:

```
perl -F'' -e '
    BEGIN{my %h}
    map { /\S/ and $h{$_}++ } @F;
    END{print map { "$_ $h{$_}\n" } keys %h}
' file
```

### Output

```
C 68
A 101
G 74
T 98
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are no blank lines or trailing spaces etc., you can use `fold` to generate a stream of single letters, and then `sort` in combination with `uniq -c` to count how many of each letter there are:

```bash
$ fold -w 1 file | sort | uniq -c
 101 A
  68 C
  74 G
  98 T
```

If there are junk whitespace characters in the input, then use an initial `tr` step to delete these characters:

```bash
$ tr -d -c 'ACGT' <file | fold -w 1 | sort | uniq -c
 101 A
  68 C
  74 G
  98 T
```

The `tr` command here will delete any character in the input that is not an `A`, `C`, `G`, or `T`.

It would be possible to replace the `sort | uniq -c` bit at the end of the pipeline with a single `awk` command that counts the occurrences of each character in the input, and then reports these:

```bash
$ tr -d -c 'ACGT' <file | fold -w 1 | awk '{ count[$0]++ } END { for (ch in count) printf "%4d %s\n", count[ch], ch }'
 101 A
  68 C
  74 G
  98 T
```

But if we're introducing `awk`, then we might as well get rid of `fold`:

```bash
$ tr -d -c 'ACGT' <file | awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i) count[substr($0,i,1)]++ } END { for (ch in count) printf "%4d %s\n", count[ch], ch }'
 101 A
  68 C
  74 G
  98 T
```

... and possibly `tr` too:

```bash
$ awk '{ gsub("[^ACGT]", ""); for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i) count[substr($0,i,1)]++ } END { for (ch in count) printf "%4d %s\n", count[ch], ch }' file
 101 A
  68 C
  74 G
  98 T
```

The `awk` code, pretty-printed:

```c
{
    gsub("[^ACGT]", "")  # removes anything not A, C, G, or T
    for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i)
        count[substr($0, i, 1)]++
}
END {
    for (ch in count) {
        printf "%4d %s\n", count[ch], ch
    }
}
```

The first block (which parses each line of input) may be rewritten to use `gsub()` rather than `substr()`:

```c
{
    count["A"] += gsub("A", "A")
    count["C"] += gsub("C", "C")
    count["G"] += gsub("G", "G")
    count["T"] += gsub("T", "T")
}
END {
    for (ch in count) {
        printf "%4d %s\n", count[ch], ch
    }
}
```

... but apart from getting a slightly less nested piece of code, this probably does not improve much on the previous code (unless it helps with readability for some user).

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='[^\n]' 'RT{cnt[RT]++} END{for (base in cnt) print base, cnt[base]}' file
A 101
C 68
T 98
G 74
```

I'm assuming that a "base" in your description is any character that isn't a newline in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
raku -e '.say for slurp.comb(/\S/).Bag.pairs;'
```

Sample Output:

```
G => 74
T => 98
A => 101
C => 68
```

Or tab-separated output (change `.say` to `.put`):

```
~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.comb(/\S/).Bag.pairs;' file
G   74
A   101
T   98
C   68
```

If you need the output sorted, add `.sort` to the end:

```
~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.comb(/\S/).Bag.pairs.sort;' file
A   101
C   68
G   74
T   98
```

Or sort by highest nucleotide count:

```
~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.comb(/\S/).Bag.pairs.sort: -*.value;' file
A   101
T   98
G   74
C   68
```

Or just count 'em all (*sans* whitespace):

```
~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.comb(/\S/).elems;' file
341
```

Finally, if you're working on really enormous files, you might want to try using `lines.join` instead of `slurp`, for better memory-management.

---

Sample Input:

```
GTCGATTGCAAGGATCCGCATGGGATAAAGGAATCGCAGTTCGAACAGGCAATGCCGCAG
CTATGATAGGACATCTCTTGGAGACACCTATTAATGTTTCAGAAACGGATACCTTGGTTG
TCCAGTACGAAATTAAGTTGGACAATTCTTTGACGTGCGGC
CTATATTAAAATTGTGGGTACATCACTCTCTTACCTGAGAATTCCAACAGAGCAGGACGC
TAACCCAGTGTCTATACCAGTCTGTGGCTTTGAAAGATTAGACACATTTCTGGATGAATT
TTCAAATTCTAAATTGATCGTTCAGTCTACACTAAGACATTCGTACGTTAGTCTTGAGAA
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

You can also count individual letters using grep

```
grep . -o inputfile | grep -c A
101
grep . -o inputfile | grep -c G
74
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun to see what happens in large files, duplicating the test file 1000 times, none of the more complex tools seemed much faster than parsing the file multiple times in a linear manner.

```
time x=$(wc -m file | cut -d ' ' -f1); for N in A C G T; do echo $N $((x - $(sed "s/"$N"//g" file | wc -m))); done

real    0m0.008s
user    0m0.010s
sys 0m0.000s
A 101000
C 68000
G 74000
T 98000
```

A bit of a sledgehammer approach, but.....